# Explanation of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Down Below I took part of a code I was looking at. I don't understand the IEnumerable part of the Code. Can someone just walk me through the meaning of each line. Thanks

I don't understand the Where(u =>) more than the rest.

```
  public static List<AAlexUsers.Models.SearchClass> Users(string userId, string email, string lastFourdigits)   
    {
        SearchClass Alex = new SearchClass();
        Alex.userId = "1234";
        Alex.email = "Alex@gmail.com";
        Alex.lastFourdigits = "1885";

        SearchClass Emilio = new SearchClass();
        Emilio.userId = "0928";
        Emilio.email = "Cubano@gmail.com";
        Emilio.lastFourdigits = "0706";

        SearchClass Ulysses = new SearchClass();
        Ulysses.userId = "0914";
        Ulysses.email = "lysses@gmail.com";
        Ulysses.lastFourdigits = "01zx";

        var list = new List<SearchClass>();
        list.Add(Alex);
        list.Add(Emilio);
        list.Add(Ulysses);

        IEnumerable<SearchClass> result = list;
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            result = result.Where(u => u.userId == userId);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
            result = result.Where(u => u.email == email);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastFourdigits))
            result = result.Where(u => u.lastFourdigits == lastFourdigits);


        return list.ToList();

    }
```

Comment: This is LINQ - if you read it as english.. what do you think it does?

Comment: why did i get a negative point?

Comment: It more sounds like "somebody can spoon feed me"

Comment: Because you probably didn't do a google search who knows

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prasadh/Enumerators11132005232321PM/Enumerators.aspx took me a second to do this google search

Comment: Probably because you didn't type "IEnumerable" into google and read any of the 10000 readily available explanations.

Comment: [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Comment: The question asks for a tutorial or link, it's not an actual problem. Hence it is off-topic on SO. Here's the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx

Comment: I would very strongly recommend you to learn C# before getting into ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: fine..i will have to delete this comment so i don't get anymore negatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IEnumerable is a collection of SearchClass objects. See it as something like a list or an array.

IEnumerable is a generic interface describing something that can be enumerated (you can iterate through it and see/retrieve all of its elements). The content of this IEnumerable can have been pre-generated, or is live/lazily generated when you try to iterate through 'result' (IEnumerable).

The next lines are queries run against this "result' list:

```
result = result.Where(u => u.userId == userId);
```

can be confusing since it assigns the return of the query to the data the query is run on.
Let's take a simpler example:

```
var myResult= myEnumerableList.Where(u => u.userId == "Yusuf");
```

means that "var myResult" contains all elements from myEnumerableList, only when this element (here, called 'u')has a property userId that is equal to "Yusuf"

.Net provides powerful ways to query collections/lists/anything_enumerable, presented with an SQL-like syntax

Answer (score 2):

Many of the LINQ methods, including `Where`, use deferred execution.  In this case you can think of the IEnumerable as a query, rather than the actual result set.  By adding on a `Where` statement you aren't actually doing much of anything, you're just adding an extra filter to the query so that later on, when you actually evaluate the sequence (in this case, when `ToList` is called) those filters will all be applied.

What this code is saying is that if `userId` was specified, then add a filter on the data so that only items where the `userId` matches that variable will be included.  That same thing is done for `email` and `lastFourdigits`.

Comment: @Jay thanks, just noticed that when re-reading.

Answer (score 1):

This is `Linq`,  (Where,Select, etc...)

`=>` this is lambda expression

and [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) is an interface for every thing iterable in .Net

You can google every part for details